# Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 + Intel 8260 Wifi = Wifi/Bluetooth issues

Tags: networking, drivers, gnome, 15.10, bluetooth

I have a clean Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 install and [Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260](http://ark.intel.com/products/86068/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-8260). The first few days Wifi/Bluetooth worked just fine.

Well, actually the Wifi was constantly disconnecting so I bought [D-Link DWA-121](http://www.dlink.com/mk/mk/support/product/dwa-121-wireless-n-150-pico-usb-adapter) external USB Wifi Adapter (no bluetooth). This adapter was recognized by the system, but I couldn't get it to work either. The network manager was activating the PCI Wifi always.

After a few reboots of the system my Bluetooth (from the PCI Wifi) disappeared. I'm getting the `No Bluetooth adapters found` message in the default Gnome Bluetooth manager.

Comment: I just installed the `wicd` network manager and removed the default `network-manager` package. I also installed the `blueman` bluetooth manager. I'm able to switch between internal and external adapters both bluetooth and wifi, and everything seems to be stable atm. Of course with these types of issues it'll take long time of testing before I can tell if the issues have disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

### Wifi

At the time of writing the Intel's 8260 Wifi card is pretty new. It is officially supported by the kernel shipped with Ubuntu 15.10 onward. In case of a [Slow Or Erratic Wi-Fi In Ubuntu 12.04 LTS? Try Wicd](http://www.techdrivein.com/2012/09/slow-erratic-wifi-ubuntu1204-fixed.html):

```
# install Wicd
sudo apt-get install wicd
# remove the default Network Manager that ships with Ubuntu
sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager
```

While I can't say that my Wifi issues have disappeared altogether at least I'm aware exactly what's going on at any given time, because Wicd shows you much more useful information than the default network manager that ships with Ubuntu. It also stores your Wifi password, so you are no longer constantly asked about your password when the manager is trying to automatically reconnect you.

In case you have external USB Wifi adapter you can easily switch between the two:

```
# list network devices
sudo lshw -C network
```

Copy the `logical name` of the network adapter you want to use in *Wicd - Preferences - General Settings - Wireless interface*

### Bluetooth

What I noticed with this particular Intel's 8260 Wifi adapter is that the Bluetooth can become a bit laggy from time to time, especially if your divce's batteries are about to die.

Another thing is that after a couple of sleep-wakeup cycles the Intel's Bluetooth adapter entry tends to disappear. No matter what command you use in the shell it's simply gone. Probably until system restart or something which is not an option for me.

So, I bought a cheap external USB Bluetooth nano adapter and I'm using it for that. I'm using the Intel's Wifi strictly for, well, Wifi. The external Bluetooth adapter works always and it delivers a bit smoother performance than the Intel's one.

I'm using Blueman to manage my devices:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

It also allows you to switch between different Bluetooth adapters (when the Intel's one is actually present :)